# Is there a way to download AdventureWorksLT2012 database as a script?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to install `AdventureWorksLT2012` database but I don't need the `.exe` installer instead I need the script file so I can copy & paste it to SSMS 2012 and run it from it so it creates it.

Is there a way to download this script from a website?

Comment: I don't think it is available as a script file, but you can download the mdf and ldf files and attach them: http://sqlserverzest.com/2013/07/31/sql-server-how-to-download-and-install-adventureworks-sample-database/

Comment: @Jaco: sure there is ! See my answer

Answer (score 2):

Go to the [Microsoft SQL Server sample database page](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com) on Codeplex and under `Other Downloads` (on the right) you can find

- [AdventureWorks for SQL Server 2012 (Mar 12, 2012 - Stable)](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330)

That page then show a lot of downloads - the one you want probably is:

- [AdventureWorks 2012 LT Script](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/373779) (third from the bottom)